# Gridview losing modified Column HeaderTexts

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am trying to dynamically modify all gridviews columns HeaderText but I keep running into issues with SOME gridviews. I was using the masterpage to modify all GridViews in a page on `Page.PreRenderComplete` and I noticed that even after changing the HeaderText the gridview displayed the old text when it loaded.

To debug I looped over the columns and modified the HeaderText of one specific Gridview in its `DataBound` event on a specific page using the following code...

```
Private Sub gv_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles gv.DataBound
    For Each col As DataControlField In gv.Columns
        col.HeaderText += "_SOMESTRING"
    Next
End Sub
```

While stepping through the page I can see this running and the header text updating. When I continue the page load and the GridView appears the header text has apparently reverted.

What could cause this to happen? Is there some event that can run after `PreRenderComplete` or after a Gridviews `Databound` event?

Comment: When I try to reproduce the problem, I run into an interesting situation: the `DataBound` event is called repeatedly until I get a `stackoverflow`. If I move the code in the `PreRender` event of the GridView however, everything works well (except that, using the code above, the header text is expanded on every postback).

Comment: I placed the same code in the GridViews PreRender event and the page still loaded with the original HeaderTexts.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, override the Render Function for the Page, not the MasterPage

```
  Protected Overrides Sub Render(ByVal writer As System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter)
    //Call function or write code that alters your gridview here
    MyBase.Render(writer)
  End Sub
```

Comment: I actually tried overriding Render. The values were set before `MyBase.Render(writer)` and maintained after `MyBase.Render(writer)` but still didnt show up on the page.

Comment: Render is the last place you can make changes before it's sent to the browser.  Because this occurs after the state is saved it needs to be called during every postback.  If you are altering header text and it doesn't appear, I have to wonder if you are modifying the right row. IIRC you need to be modifying `gv.HeaderRow`

Comment: also in looking at your original code, you are using the gv.DataBound event.  you should be using gv.HeaderRow there as well.  However, the DataBound event may not always be called during the page lifecycle so you are still better off doing this in gv.prerender or page.render or page.prerendercomplete.  these all always get called

Comment: I was actually just  testing it there because I knew it would be hit. Once i figure out how to get it to work the plan is for it to happen in Page.PreRenderComplete. Is there a functional difference between HeaderRow and Columns(i).HeaderText?

Comment: yes: [GridView.HeaderRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.headerrow(v=vs.110).aspx) vs [DataControlField.HeaderText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datacontrolfield.headertext(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thanks fnostro! I decided to revisit HeaderRow and it ended up being what I needed. It looks like the Header texts are stored as controls in the HeaderRow. The reason I had missed them originally was because I was assuming they were either Labels or LinkButtons. It turns out non sortable column texts are `DataControlFieldHeaderCell`s and sortable columns are `DataControlLinkButton`. `DataControlLinkButton` was a bit weird, I had to compare its type name as text and cast it as a LinkButton.